# How do I web scrape the following college ranking data from WSJ in R?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape all 400 entries of WSJ's college rankings in R. I am using the `rvest` package in R as follows:

```
library(rvest)
link <- "https://www.wsj.com/rankings/college-rankings/best-colleges-2024"
wsj <- read_html(link)
```

After this, I'm pretty lost on what to do next. The HTML source code for the page is really messy and hard to sift through. I feel like I've made some progress by doing:

```
wsj %>% html_elements("section")  %>% html_element("p")
```

But I'm very new to this, so I may not be on the right track. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

All of the data on the webpage is stored as JSON data in a script node.  After searching the webpage here is quick solution.

Once one retrieves the data in the script node, convert it to text, then parse the JSON data into a list.  One needs to read through the list in order to identify the correct list structure.

```
library(rvest)
link <- "https://www.wsj.com/rankings/college-rankings/best-colleges-2024"
wsj <- read_html(link)

#Retrieve the script node whose id=__NEXT_DATA__
#convert to text
#then parse with the jsonlite library.
webdata <- wsj %>% html_elements("script[id='__NEXT_DATA__']") %>% 
                   html_text() %>% jsonlite::fromJSON()

#looking through the output the college rank data is stored here.
collegedata <- webdata$props$pageProps$collegeRankingsData

head(collegedata)
tail(collegedata)
```

Comment: Great job! A little mistake : collegedata <- webdata$props$pageProps$collegeRankingsData

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!